# XCode couldnot launch app "The operation could not be completed (FBSOpenApplicaionpplicaionErrorDomain error 3.)"

Tags: ios, xcode

Every time, I run my project I got this warning. I tried to restart XCode but it still not work.

[image]

Any idea to fix it

Answer (score 1):

do like `Reset` your `Simulator` and try it works

**iOS Simulator -> Reset Contents and Settings -> Reset**